# How to list all milestones in a github user or organization

Tags: github, github-api

At this time I can see the milestones of one repository at a time (i.e. one by one). For example, I can do that navigating these links:

- https://github.com/codenautas/dialog-promise/milestones and
- https://github.com/codenautas/backend-plus/milestones

but [codenautas](https://github.com/codenautas) organization has many projects. Someone of thats projects have many milestones.

I'm trying to ask: How is the way to list all the milestones of one organization in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milestones are only listable by repository in the API, so you can't get all organisation milestones in one query—you're forced to do it the O(n<sup>2</sup>) way by iterating over each repository in your organisation and concatenating each milestone.

You can mitigate against this somewhat by using the API's [conditional requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests) feature: each request will return an `ETag`, which you can then send back using the `If-None-Match` header—if the response hasn't changed then you'll receive back a `304 Not Modified` that won't count against your rate limit.